# Mismatch in the fields viewed from setup and workbench

Tags: sales

I am looking at the fields on Order Product (OrderItem) from setup and from workbench. On #1 there is a product lookup which is not present when viewed from workbench #2. Same is with pricebookentry which is present on workbench view #2 but not in #1 setup view.
[image: Snashpot #1]

[image: Snaphot #2]

Any help on this mismatch would be helpful. Which one is correct, Am I looking at wrong data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happens with Opportunity Line Items. A somewhat loose explanation is that, on the UI we see a product (and can click on it and be redirected to the product page), but on the background this association is really to a PriceBookEntry (with is a junction object so we can set prices).

Comment: This is weired. So Pricebook entry needs to be present. Yes on page layout of order product direct lookup to product is shown. I guess this is managed internally by SF. That created more confusion. Thanks Fernando for confirming.